# Run php file via command line on an ubuntu linux server

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php file on a ubuntu linux server but get a 'command not found' error when i run "php file_name.php"

Searching online, i found an article that suggested I run "sudo aptitude install php5-cli" which I did and restarted apache afterwards but I still get this error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please paste output of following commands: "dpkg -L php5-cli" and "update-alternatives --list php"

Comment: Package 'php5-cli' is not installed while the update-alternatives gave error no alternatives for php

Comment: That means you do not have PHP installed. What were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 5):

Try this once,

Go to terminal.

```
whereis php
```

It will show where is php installed.

Export that path to environment variable using following command

```
export PATH=$PATH;/path/to/php's/bin directory
```

Then execute required file..

As follows,

```
php file_to_execute.php
```

Answer (score 2):

first make sure that you've installed following packs:

- php5
- php5-cli
- php-pear

like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli php-pear
```

then make sure to configure php safely befor using it.

also make your php file executable ( chmod 700 )

Answer (score 0):

- Try the following step :
- Open your cmd/console or press ctr+alt+t.
- php5  /your/path/to/php_file_name.