# How to find PHP executable in Xampp - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

After installing Xampp on Ubuntu, where can I find the PHP executable to put it in the `/usr/bin` folder so that I can use the PHP alias globally?

[image]

Comment: look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157163/run-php-file-via-command-line-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server#answer-12157583)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple:

```
whereis php
```

Solved the problem.

*Note: The response author has deleted the comment. Thank you anyway.*

Comment: Wow dude! Thank you. Lack of attention of mine, because I had already visited this folder, but had not found anything. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cheers!! :D I deleted comment because i found someone already answered better for it.

Comment: It's all right! Do you want to respond? So I can give the credits to you. :)

Comment: No that's fine. You can up vote the answer in link which i commented below question.

Answer (score 6):

the php executable file is located

> opt/lampp/bin/php

you can also find it with this command

```
$ whereis php
```